# antd different style in development and build mode

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have this strange issue with antd table. Particularly *the
alignment of text of the placeholder when there is no data in the table which looks like this (not centered):*

[image: screenshot]

This was code:

```
 <Table  size="small"
         locale={{emptyText: "No data"}}
         columns={columns}
         dataSource={data}
  />
```

The strange thing is this same web app when uploaded on a site (build with yarn run build), the **text is centered**.

Using antd version: antd@^4.1.4 (from yarn.lock).

Strangely I can't reproduce using their original code: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-ant-design-demo-4bgyj?file=/index.js (**Text is center aligned** as you see on sandbox too).

What centers this text is this rule which lacks in my development mode but is present both on sandbox and on my site (build with yarn run build).

```
.ant-table-tbody>tr.ant-table-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Can someone give some explanation why in my development mode this rule is missing and text is not center aligned?**

Comment: Could be caching issue, clear local data on your local browser

Comment: Did you eject the react scripts?